# Get only the elements which are not hidden.. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get only the show() element in jquery foreach loop

In the below code i am getting all the element with class test (i.e) both hidden and shown...  but need only shown and not hidden one... how to filter and get that in this line itself?????

```
$('.element').find('.test').each(function(index, loopelement) {

 }
```

Comment: It's really worth the hour (or two, *max*) that it takes to read through the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. You'll find all sorts of things you didn't know about (including the `:visible` selector Rory's pointed out).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector:

```
$('.element').find('.test:visible').each(function(index, loopelement) {
    // do stuff...
});
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, but the question was "...both hidden and shown...". I mean, I am not arguing about the docs. I have read them and that is why I making this comment as this solution is "not exacly the answer to the question"

Comment: @Pisek I'm not sure what you mean. The OP says he's currently getting all the elements (both hidden and shown) and he wants to change that behaviour so that the selector only returns the elements that are shown - which is exactly what my answer does.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, the title of this issue is `Get only the elements which are not hidden.. Jquery`. And in jQuery docs for *:visible*: `Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.`. So, as I said before: Your answer is not correct... You will select elements which are *visible* or *hidden*. You will only omit *display: none* elements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, sorry but no;) Your answer is just wrong. Again, the question was *...but need only shown and not hidden one...*. Your code will not work for hidden elements! It is not about semantics - hidden is hidden, not-displayed is not-displayed. Be strict about that. Your code will only work for not-displayed elements. Mate, I have just shown you the mistake you did. If you want to fix it, do it whatever way you like. I just came here to find the answer to a question, and sorry but the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [jQuery's :visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

```
var $visibles = $(".element").find(".test:visible");
```

But be aware of how jQuery works. From jQuery documentation:

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible,
>   since they still consume space in the layout.

In case this behaviour doesn't fit your use case you could extend jQuery, creating your own custom selector:

```
$.expr[":"].reallyVisible =
    function reallyVisible (elem) {
        if (elem == null || elem.tagName == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (elem.tagName.toLowerCase() === "script" || elem.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input" && elem.type === "hidden") {
            return false;
        }

        do {
            if (!isVisible(elem)) {
                return false;
            }

            elem = elem.parentNode;
        } while (elem != null && elem.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "html");

        return true;
    };

function isVisible (elem) {
    var style = elem.style;

    // Depending on your use case
    // you could check the height/width, or if it's in the viewport...
    return !(style.display === "none" || style.opacity === "0" || style.visibility === "hidden");
}
```

It can be used as any other built-in selector:

```
$(".element").find(".test:reallyVisible");
$(".element").find(".test:first").is(":reallyVisible");
```