# multiple select remove disable button if select is not empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, attributes

I'm working with multiple select, and i want to remove the attribute `disabled` button if all select has value, however the "technician" has sub item which is required and other phase don't have sub.

I wan't to remove disable attribute if all select(NO SUB) has value, and select(with sub) has value.

Here's my code:

```js
const type = document.getElementById("empType");
const phase = document.getElementById("phase");
const subPhase = document.getElementById("subPhase");


type.addEventListener("change", appendPhase);

function appendPhase(){
  $("#phase").empty();
  var option = '';
  if(type.value == 1){
      option += '<option value="0">SELECT</option><option value="1">Trainee</option><option value="2">Acting</option><option value="3">Competency</option>'
  }
  if(type.value == 2){
      option += '<option value="0">SELECT</option><option value="1">Phase 1</option><option value="2">Phase 2</option>'
  }  
  if(type.value == 0){
      $(subPhase).attr("hidden", true);
      option += '<option value="0">SELECT</option>'
  }
  $(phase).append(option);
  $(subPhase).attr("hidden", true);
}

phase.addEventListener("change", showIfTech);

function showIfTech() {
  if(type.value == 2){
    $(subPhase).attr("hidden", false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="empType">
  <option value="0">SELECT</option>
  <option value="1">LINE LEADER</option>
  <option value="2">TECHNICIAN</option>
</select>

<select id="phase">
  <option value="0">SELECT</option>
</select>

<select id="subPhase" hidden>
  <option value="0">SELECT</option>
  <option value="1">COMMON</option>
  <option value="2">ELECTRICAL</option>
  <option value="3">MECHANICAL</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<button disabled>CHECK ME</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to add `id` attribute to `button` to use it later.

Second, use event listner `change` (using event delegation) to listen all select boxes change where it is not hidden with selector `select:not([hidden])`. And then test that all select boxes are selected where value is not `0`.

Here is the code.

```js
const type = document.getElementById("empType");
const phase = document.getElementById("phase");
const subPhase = document.getElementById("subPhase");


type.addEventListener("change", appendPhase);

function appendPhase() {
  $("#phase").empty();
  var option = '';
  if (type.value == 1) {
    option += '<option value="0">SELECT</option><option value="1">Trainee</option><option value="2">Acting</option><option value="3">Competency</option>'
  }
  if (type.value == 2) {
    option += '<option value="0">SELECT</option><option value="1">Phase 1</option><option value="2">Phase 2</option>'
  }
  if (type.value == 0) {
    $(subPhase).attr("hidden", true);
    option += '<option value="0">SELECT</option>'
  }
  $(phase).append(option);
  $(subPhase).attr("hidden", true);
}

phase.addEventListener("change", showIfTech);

function showIfTech() {
  if (type.value == 2) {
    $(subPhase).attr("hidden", false);
  }
}


document.addEventListener('change', isAllSelected);

function isAllSelected() {
  let allSelected = [];
  const allSelectBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('select:not([hidden])');
  allSelectBoxes.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.value != '0') {
      allSelected.push(item.value);
    }
  });

  const checkMeButton = document.getElementById('check-me-button');
  if (allSelected.length === allSelectBoxes.length) {
    checkMeButton.disabled = false;
  } else {
    checkMeButton.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="empType">
  <option value="0">SELECT</option>
  <option value="1">LINE LEADER</option>
  <option value="2">TECHNICIAN</option>
</select>

<select id="phase">
  <option value="0">SELECT</option>
</select>

<select id="subPhase" hidden>
  <option value="0">SELECT</option>
  <option value="1">COMMON</option>
  <option value="2">ELECTRICAL</option>
  <option value="3">MECHANICAL</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<button id="check-me-button" disabled>CHECK ME</button>
```

Comment: can i ask how to change this selector "document.querySelectorAll('select:not([hidden])')" if i put my select inside div. then that div where will i put my hidden attribute... Because later ill put label on it. i also want to hide the label. sooo i think i better put it inside div or no? @vee

Comment: @Strywyr You may use jQuery `:visible`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13949759/128761) as example. Please note that they use different `.each()`. Example: `$('select:visible')`.

Comment: Or use [`.offsetXXX` to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom).